# Repeated iCloud prompts

Tags: ios, icloud, ipad

I get repeated requests to supply my iCloud password each time I use my iPad.  I can just hit cancel and move on, but will get the popup again in a few minutes.  Is there a way to stop this?  I do not use the back-up feature to secure my information.

Comment: What happens if you just give it the password, instead of trying to make it just go away?

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually have iCLoud signed out.  The first thing to do is give it the current password for the account listed, then once it reconnects go to Settings > iCloud and use the signout link to completely and properly signout of iCloud.